# Is there any database system which I can use it without installation

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, database, sqlite

I am designing a small program, which I want to use a database to manage my data. I want a database which I may put it into my system, so that users may use it without install any database system.

So is there any database suit for my project requirement?

Programming Language: Java
Platform: cross-platform (linux, windows, mac)

There are three reasons why I want to use an embedded database system

1. there is not too much information in my system
2. what I wish it user may directly to use my system without to setup any database
3. I also wish when I copy my system from computer A to computer B, it may keep all data

besides database, I also consider to manage data with XML file, but I don't think it is a good idea to use XML, because it is not easy to update or delete data.

AND this is my first time to use stackoverflow, so there are some culture I am not very clear. If I offended stackoverflow, please forgive me.

Comment: why would the users have to ever install a database system for your project? your database is used to store information for them... they use the system/project/program. not the database system. so either you did not provide enough information with this question, or the users wouldn't need to install a database system

Answer (score 2):

I use [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) in java.

For following scenario:

1. h2 is really small (about 1Mb), it is easy to copy, and easy to use with maven, gradle, etc.
2. h2 is pure java db, when I want to write unit test on my DAO java code, it is easy to start.
3. h2 can simulate oracle dialect、mysql dialect. After I built a demo with h2, it is easy to move all java code to work with a big DB system.
4. In H2 jdbc URL, it is easy to config a init SQL script in a file. By this feature, It is easy to create a clear database with only necessary data in it.
5. When you want to share your data, you can simply release your database file with your production, which is difficult for Oracle or MySQL.

Another real example is [Atlassian Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/try/?tab=download). You may download and install Confluence, start it with h2 for trial. When you decide to use it in business, set it up to connect MySQL or Oracle.

Comment: my programming language is java, and my platform is linux and windows

Comment: It's ok, h2 don't care what OS do you use. It's only a small jar file, can persist data into file on your disk or store data in memory only.

Comment: This should be a comment.  But since your reputation is too low to make them, I'm upvoting your answer to get you closer to being able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a common choice. You can embed the database core functionality as a library in your app. The only local resource required is plain vanilla files on the normal file system -- no drivers, daemons etc.